# gcloud scheduler create jobs when already exist

Tags: gcloud, scheduler, exists

I create my gcloud scheduler in command line with

```
gcloud scheduler jobs create
```

but when I already deploy my gitlabCI, i got already exist error.

is it possible to overwrite if already exist directly in my gitlabCI ?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you create a Cloud Schedule job with the following attribute values

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs create JOB --location=LOCATION
```

| JOB | LOCATION |
| --- | --- |
| my-job | us-west1 |

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs create my-job --location=us-west1
```

In order to verify if the job already exists you may use the `gcloud schedule jobs describe JOB` command using gcloud CLI .e.g https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler/jobs/describe

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs describe my-job --location=us-west1
```

If it indeed already exists, there is no direct way of "overwriting" the existing one, what you can do is to

- either delete the previous job and re-create it from scratch e.g.

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs delete my-job
gcloud scheduler jobs create my-job
```

- or you can modify the existing job, for instance when you deploy a new version of a service to AppEngine, you can simply reflect this on your existing Cloud Scheduler job without the need to re-creating it entirely.

```bash
gcloud scheduler jobs update app-engine my-job --version=VERSION
```

For more information, please refer to the official documentation for Cloud SDK on Cloud Scheduler https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/scheduler

Comment: No problem. Was it helpful resolving your original problem?

Comment: Not really, because I have to check in my gitlabCI if gcloud jobs list return a value

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following steps in your `.gitlab-ci` file:

1. list all scheduler jobs and use a filter to narrow down to your scheduler job. Use something unique to your scheduler job, e.g. `description`?
2. Delete the existing job.
3. Re-create your scheduler job

```bash
    # list scheduler jobs
    - >
      gcloud scheduler jobs list
      --location="LOCATION"
      --filter "description='The description for your existing scheduler job'"
      --project "YOUR_PROJECT_ID"
      --format json
      > list.json
    
    # delete the existing scheduler job
    - >
      for i in $(jq -r .[].name list.json); do
        gcloud scheduler jobs delete $i --quiet --project $YOUR_PROJECT_ID || echo "Failed to delete $i"
      done

    # now re-create your scheduler job
    - >
      gcloud scheduler jobs create your-scheduler-job
```